# problem with installing ubuntu 14.04 via wubi

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I have problem with installing ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop (asus x550cc) with Windows 7 x64 via wubi. After running wubi.exe as an administrator, it don't start. I don't have python installed. I was trying install ubuntu x86 and x64. Exist any way to run it alternative way? 
I'm trying to use wubi, cause I can't install 2 systems on laptop (some problems with bios - this laptop have something like hybrid between normal bios and uefi. 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Did you try Wubi version on iso or [coummnity supported version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases) (see [Wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info) )?

Comment: I was trying to use wubi on iso. I will try coummnity supported version :)

Answer (score 0):

WuBi support was officially dropped on Ubuntu 12.10, I have an Asus x550c and you just need to disable Fast boot and switch from legacy bios to UEFI, also take care of create a UEFI bootable USB disk.

Comment: During instalation ubuntu from live-usb, instalator don't detect other system and partitions created early. I was trying to install it using normal and uefi boot, first Windows or first Ubuntu (this way instalator don't recognize partition made early). Only type of bios witch can be run is Aptio Setup Utility - it don't have fast boot function.

Answer (score 0):

WUBI is no longer supported, and won't work on a UEFI computer. So you can't use it :(.

But you can easily install Ubuntu now, as EFI makes it easier to create a USB disk.